# Tampermonkey & download dialogs

Tags: greasemonkey, userscripts, tampermonkey

After reading through the documentation, I figure not, but better safe than sorry :

Can user scripts interact with a download dialog, changing the file name? The file name is not known before clicking the download link so it's not simply a matter of finding foo.bar.zip on the page and replacing foo.bar by the new name.

Comment: It would be useful to know why you want it closed, whomever you are :)

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Yes, you can explicitly specify file name via the `download` attribute:

```
<a href="index.html" download="test.html">Download index page</a>
```

However there are caveats:

- If server sends file name in the [`Content-Disposition`](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/HTTP/Headers/Content-Disposition) header, that header is prefered over what you specified
- This only works on links within the same domain and protocol

If you're on the same domain, the `Content-Disposition` header can be erased if you download the file via `XMLHttpRequest` and then use `createObjectURL` and have the user download that. Ask yourself if it's worth the effort.